# Get the latest message in the queue

Tags: rabbitmq, queue

I want to fetch the last / latest message added in the queue, is there a specific option available in the `rabbitmqadmin` utility.

The following command is giving the first message in the queue,

`./rabbitmqadmin get queue='log' -H localhost -P 15672 -u <username> -p <password> --vhost=logging count=1`

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to consume or view the messages? I use this tool [plumber](https://github.com/batchcorp/plumber) to view the latest incoming messages without removing them from the queue. If you are looking to consume just the latest message you may have to write a script.

To read the latest inbound message and exit:

```
plumber read messages rabbitmq --address amqp://user@pass:127.0.0.1:5672 --exchange events --routing-key \#
```

To watch all messages as they come in:

```
plumber read messages RabbitMQ --address amqp://user@pass:127.0.0.1:5672 --exchange events --routing-key \# --follow
```

If you use plumber your queue must be set up on its own exchange you can not use the RabbitMQ default exchange [see](https://www.scommerce-mage.com/blog/rabbitmq-creating-queues-and-bindings-from-a-command-line.html).